# pagination codeigniter just load partly item in next page

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

I have problem in codeigniter, if me click next page just load partly item. Example if page 1 item display  A,B,C,D,E,F in page 2 item display to be D,E,F,G,H,I should be G,H,I,J,K,L in page 2 i don't know what wrong in my code.

This link my code : http://pastebin.com/45fS2AiX

Thanks

Comment: Can you post your codes? The link can't access from here.

Comment: Read this tutorial http://w3code.in/2015/10/how-to-do-pagination-in-codeigniter/

Answer (score 1):

This is part of your code

```
$data['categoryHead'] = $this->M_home->listCategory();
$this->load->view('frontend/template/header', $data);//line 2
$data['productsLast'] = $this->M_home->listProductLast();
$data['productsLast2'] = $this->M_home->listProductLast2();
$data['category'] = $this->M_home->listCategory();

$config['base_url'] = base_url().'categoryproduct/'.$this->session->userdata('sesi_id');
$config['total_rows'] = $this->M_home->listProductPerCategory_num_rows();
$config['per_page'] = 12;
$config['first_link']           = 'First';
$config['last_link']            = 'Last';
$config['next_link']            = 'Next';
$config['prev_link']            = 'Prev';
$config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;
```

> In **Line number 2 you load view**. So it will load view as your command before render the pagination data.

**In Model**

```
function listProductPerCategory($limit1,$limit2){

    $session =$this->session->userdata('sesi_id');
    $sql = "SELECT category.category, product.id, product.picture, product.name, product.part_no FROM product, category
            WHERE category.id=product.id_category AND product.id_category = '$session' ORDER BY product.part_no ASC  LIMIT $limit2, $limit1";

    $query = $this->db->query($sql);
    $result = $query->result_array();

    $count = count($result);
    if(empty($count)){

       return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return $result; 
    }    
}

//count
function listProductPerCategory_num_rows(){

    $session =$this->session->userdata('sesi_id');
    $sql = "SELECT category.category, product.id, product.picture, product.name, product.part_no FROM product, category
            WHERE category.id=product.id_category AND product.id_category = '$session'";

    $query = $this->db->query($sql);
    $result = $query->result_array();

    $count = count($result);

    return $count;    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace this code :

```
$page = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ? $this->uri->segment(3) : 0;
```

to

```
$page = $this->uri->segment(3) ? ($this->uri->segment(3) - 1) * $config['per_page'] : 0;
```

Comment: wow !! thanks @Bipin Kareparambil it's working :-), but can you explain me about that

Comment: For example, if you set $config['per_page'] = 10, then in page 2 data must be fetch from 11th onwards. So the $page =  (2-1)*10 = 10. Then the database offset will start fetching data from the 11th row.
Please accept this answer if you are satisfied.